# How do depmod, insmod, kmod, lsmod, modinfo, modprobe, and rmmod all relate?

Tags: linux, modprobe

I'm getting conflicting information from the manuals, especially regarding `kmod` and `modprobe`. All of these programs come together in the same package, but are any f these backends or frontends? Does `modprobe` call `insmod` and `rmmod`? Does `depmod` call `modinfo` when building a list of dependencies? Is `kmod` used as a backend by `insmod` and `rmmod`?

From [`kmod.8.man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/kmod.8.html):

```
 kmod is a multi-call binary which implements the programs used to
 control Linux Kernel modules. Most users will only run it using its
 other names.
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of those are just symlinks to kmod.  kmod then checks the name it's invoked with -- probably with argv[0] (never looked at the source to see for sure) to determine its behavior.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 26  2012 depmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 26  2012 insmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 26  2012 lsmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 26  2012 modinfo -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 26  2012 modprobe -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Aug 26  2012 rmmod -> /bin/kmod
```